# Switch with typedef enum type from string

Tags: objective-c, enums, nsstring, switch-statement

I'm trying to get a value from a string that belongs to an enum typedef in Obj C but I don't seem capable of geting the value out of the NSString. I'me doing something like this:

```
typedef enum{
    S,
    M,
    L
} Size;

-(void)function:(NSString *)var{
Size value=[var value];
swicth(value){
  case S:...
  case M:...
  ...
 }
}
```

EDIT:
The contents of the string would br something like @"S" @"M" @"L"

I don't see how can I accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you know that the strings are of length one, you can switch on the `unichar` at position 0.

```
switch ([string characterAtIndex:0]) {
case 'S': ...
case 'L': ...
case 'M': ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the string contains. Is it `@"S"`, `@"M"` or `@"L"`? If so, you need to provide your own conversion to the values of the `Size` enumeration. Or you *could* just use string comparison in your method:

```
if ([var isEqualToString: @"S"]) {
  // ...
} else if ([var isEqualToString: @"M"]) {
  //...
} ...
```

However, if the string contains the numeric value of one of the `Size` entries (like `@"0"`, `@"1"` or `@"2"`) you can use the `-intValue` method to do the comparison you wrote in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear about the string contents, yes they would be @"S" @"M" @"L" and using if else would defeat the purpose of using a switch.